# How to sort items from shortest to longest

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

In Sublime Text, is there any way to sort items below to shortest to longest?
I don't know if this helps, but I am using Vintage mode.

```
use App\Article;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\ArticleRequest;
use App\Tag;
use App\User;
use Gate;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Mews\Purifier\Facades\Purifier;
```

What I am trying to achieve is that select all the items, trigger some command and have them sorted shortest to longest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1. There is a [thread on the Sublime Text forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sort-lines-lengthwise/7547/4) in which a user provides plugin code (disclaimer: I haven't actually tried it myself):

   ```
    import sublime, sublime_plugin
    import sort

    def line_length_sort(txt):
        txt.sort(lambda a, b: cmp(len(a), len(b)))
        return txt

    class SortLinesLengthCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
        def run(self, edit, reverse=False, remove_duplicates=False):
            view = self.view

            sort.permute_lines(line_length_sort, view, edit)

            if reverse:
                sort.permute_lines(sort.reverse_list, view, edit)

            if remove_duplicates:
                sort.permute_lines(sort.uniquealise_list, view, edit)
   ```
2. You can install the [SortBy plugin](https://github.com/Doi9t/SortBy). It provides many advanced sorting commands, including `SortBy: Length of lines`.

On Windows:

Sort By String Options & Key Bindings

[image: Sort By String Options & Key Bindings]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
SortBy: Alphabetically Ascending

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
SortBy: Alphabetically Descending

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>
SortBy: LengthOf Lines Ascending

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
SortBy: LengthOf Lines Descending

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>
SortBy: Natural Order Ascending

Sort By Number Options & Key Bindings

[image: Sort By Number Options & Key Bindings]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
SortBy: Binary Ascending

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>
SortBy: Binary Descending

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
SortBy: Hexadecimal Ascending

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
SortBy: Hexadecimal Descending

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>
SortBy: Interger Ascending

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
SortBy: Interger Descending

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
SortBy: Octal Ascending

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
SortBy: Octal Descending

Menu Location:

[image: Menu Location]

Comment: The plugin does exactly what I wanted to do thanks for the tip